# switf - Dynamic mask for UITextField

Tags: swift, mask

There's a way to do something like `**onTextChanged**` from Java?
I need a dynamic `mask` to brazilian phone number, who is based characters numbers (`## ####-####` or `## #####-####`).

Is there a way to do this on **Swift 3**?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) { }
```

Comment: One question: What if I have two `textField`with `textFieldDidChange`, how I manage it?

Comment: you have to loop all your textFields..